# Select Record with Date closest to date passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, parameters

I have two tables one holds the most recent value of a position and the other is an archive that holds all other values. I like to build a query that selects the position value closest to the date passed in.
The most recent date will always be in the Positions table and everything older will always be in the archive. 
Right now there is a datediff that looks at whether the date in the up-to-date table or the date archive table is closer and then chooses which one. I'm looking for a simpler approach that possibly does this in the join. of the select
As you can see below this query is not too nice. Trying to come up with a way to do it in the join.
The date closest will be something equal to or in the past of the date passed in not in the future. So the below example I expect to get the 2014-04-06 75800.00 back for posid 1714 and the 2013-11-05 950.00 row back for 2240
Edit: SQL SERVER 2008R2

```
DECLARE @dtAsOFDate DATETIME= '2014-04-11'

select a.iID
 ,mp.iposid
 ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,mp.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfdate) <= ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,mpa.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfdate),999999) 
                    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,mp.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfDate)>=0 
                                    THEN mp.dtAsOfDate 
                                    ELSE mpa.dtAsOFDate END 
,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,mp.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfdate) <= ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY,mpa.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfdate),999999) 
                    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,mp.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfDate)>=0 
                                    THEN mp.mPosValue 
                                    ELSE mpa.mPosValue END 


from #accountIDs a with (nolock)
join positions p with (nolock)on mp.iaccountid=a.iaccountid
left join positionsarchive mpa with (nolock) on mp.iposid=mpa.iposid
AND mpa.dtASOfdate=(SELECT max(dtASOfDate) FROM dbo.PositionsArchive WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE     mpa.iID=iID and mpa.iPosID=iPosID and dtASOfDate<=@dtASOfDate)
```

Sample data:

iID  iPosID    MostRecentDate MostRecentValue  ArchiveDate ArchiveValue

-1427770      1714    2014-04-06      75800.00     2014-04-02        67800.00

-1529470       2240    2014-11-05     95.00     2013-11-05         950.00

Comment: I added the sql-server tag basedon the syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that part. Sql Server 2008

Comment: How do you know the date doesn't have several closer dates in the archive?

Comment: In that current select. I'm selecting the max closest to the date in the join.

Comment: . . I can see that your query works that way.  According to your desired logic, this query doesn't do what you really want.

Comment: The most recent date will always be in the ManualPositions table and everything older will always be in the archive. I am 100% sure of this as that is the way the tables are created/ how records get into the archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @dtAsOFDate DATETIME = '2014-04-11'

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;       --Easier to employ than WITH (NOLOCK)

; WITH
    CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT
            a.iaccountid
            , mp.imanualposid
            , mp.dtAsOfDate
            , mp.mPosValue
            , ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,mp.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfdate)) AS daysAway
        FROM #accountIDs a
            INNER JOIN manualpositions mp ON mp.iaccountid = a.iaccountid
        WHERE mp.iAccountID = a.iaccountid
        UNION SELECT
            a.iaccountid
            , mpa.imanualposid
            , mpa.dtAsOfDate
            , mpa.mPosValue
            , ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,mpa.dtASOfDate,@dtASOfdate)) AS daysAway
        FROM #accountIDs a
            INNER JOIN manualpositionsarchive mpa ON mpa.iaccountid = a.iaccountid
        WHERE mpa.iAccountID = a.iaccountid
    )
    ,
    CTE2 AS
    (
        SELECT
            iaccountid
            , imanualposid
            , dtAsOfDate
            , mPosValue
            , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY imanualposid ORDER BY daysAway ASC)
        FROM CTE1
    )
SELECT
    iaccountid
    , imanualposid
    , dtAsOfDate
    , mPosValue
FROM CTE2
WHERE RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY
    iaccountid ASC
    , imanualposid ASC
```

Comment: I went with something along these lines but built it into my join rather than CTE's

Answer (score 0):

I would think `outer apply` for this.  Something like the following query:

```
DECLARE @dtAsOFDate DATETIME= '2014-04-11';

select a.iaccountid, mp.imanualposid,
       (CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, mp.dtASOfDate, @dtASOfdate)) >
                  ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, mpa.dtASOfDate, @dtASOfdate))
              THEN mpa.dtAsOFDate ELSE mp.dtAsOfDate 
        END) as ClosestDate
from #accountIDs a with (nolock) join
     manualpositions mp with (nolock)
     on mp.iaccountid = a.iaccountid outer apply
     (select top 1 mpa.*
      from manualpositionsarchive mpa with (nolock)
      where mp.imanualposid = mpa.imanualposid
      order by abs(datediff(day, mpa.dtAsOfDate, @dtAsOfDate) )
     ) mpa
```

EDIT:

If you want the most recent date less than or equal to, then the query would be quite similar:

```
select a.iaccountid, mp.imanualposid,
       (CASE WHEN mp.dtASOfDate > @dtASOfdate
             THEN mp.dtAsOfDate 
             ELSE mpa.dtAsOFDate
        END) as ClosestDate
from #accountIDs a with (nolock) join
     manualpositions mp with (nolock)
     on mp.iaccountid = a.iaccountid outer apply
     (select top 1 mpa.*
      from manualpositionsarchive mpa with (nolock)
      where mp.imanualposid = mpa.imanualposid and mpa.dtAsOfDate < @dtAsOfDate
      order by mpa.dtAsOfDate desc
     ) mpa
```

Comment: I'd like to get rid of the case statement so that it just returns the most recent record that is closest (not newer) to the date passed in